# How can I add info on a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

If I look at the tag-page for Mercurial there's an [Info tab-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=mercurial&sort=info&pagesize=15), that contains a URL to the company that makes Mercurial, some general info on Mercurial and so on.

How can I add this info for another tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page itself should contain the limit so you know how far you are from reaching it.

[sad panda http://shog9.com/so_meta_58421_votecount.png](http://shog9.com/so_meta_58421_votecount.png)

Comment: then we might have a bug: http://yfrog.com/1gsotaginfobugp for a screenshot. The only info shown is how 'credible' I am for that specific tag.
EDIT: I can see how many times I'm upvoted for that specific tag, not how much 'score' I need to edit the shown info.

Comment: @Ton: yeah, it should probably tell you how many votes you need to edit...

Comment: As usual it's hidden in a tooltip: "when you reach 100 upvotes you are able to edit the tag wiki". Not sure if this was just added or not, it just occurred to me to check now

Comment: Actually you need at least 101 upvotes, so the tooltip is slightly inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you need the same upvotes for proposing a tag-synonym?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the info page of the tag. If you made enough rep/have enough upvotes for this tag, you can edit the info page. Otherwise: tough luck.